# Make .git-ftp-ignore ignore everything except a few files / directories

Tags: git, web-deployment, git-ftp

How can I for example make git-ftp ignore the whole directory "foo" but not "foo/bar/"?

Answer (score 0):

i read somewhere that with git 2.9+ you can do it as

```
#untrack foo
foo/

# track foo/bar
!foo/bar/
```